# Editing table values on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to delete a character of our choice...?

Say in a table we have values which have "www.example.com" Suppose I want to remove "www" from all the entries in a table... how to do that?

Suppose table id is "tab09".

How can I write a code in js such that as the page loads the chars "www" are removed from tab09?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tab09 td').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/^www\./,''));
 });
});
```

Comment: Note that this uses jQuery which you can include in your page with `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` above the snippet I gave.

Comment: Also possible with pure JS if jQuery is not an option but naturally requires much more lines of code.. :)

Comment: Yes I agree, but this is not working.... I have imported jquery.js in my local system !!

Comment: @New to this: please elaboate on "not working" - what exactly is happening? Try replacing something more obvious just to see the concept is working.

Comment: I will explain the scenario in detail :- I have a table with huge data.... Around 20000 rows. I need to delete certain set of characters say double quotes("). I can do this using JSTL tag <fn:replace functionality. But I am not sure about the efficiency of the same. I am new to jQuery so is there any solution in this aspect. Please let me know.

Comment: For 20000 rows, it would make more sense to do this server side instead.

Comment: @New to this: the code provided in this answer should work and that's the way to do it with jQuery, but it will cause the browser to freeze for several seconds if you have that much data. What server side language do you have?

Comment: Thats the issue. Currently the application is taking time to load... it freezes for a few seconds. How can we do it in an efficient way? We have to do the changes in jsp or js files only.. My challenge now is to delete all the double quotes(") values in the table. Eg ; "I am Rock" must be displayed as I am Rock. " Must be removed. Iteration will also cause issues. How can JQuery help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using regular Javascript you would do:

```
var modifyTable = function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("tab09"),
        tds = table ? table.getElementsByTagName("td") : null;

    if (tds) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
            tds[i].innerHTML = tds[i].innerHTML.replace(/www\./, "");
        }
    }
};

if (document.addEventListener) // DOM ready
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", modifyTable, false);
else if (window.attachEvent) // IE, just use onload this time.
    window.attachEvent("onload", modifyTable);
```

**EDIT**: As thirtydot pointed out, without listening to DOM readiness, the code must be placed after the `table` element. Added listener.

Comment: This must be placed after the `table` element, or it must otherwise be made to run after the DOM has loaded.